# How to check if $scope variable is an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a check to see if `$scope.digitalSelect` is an array and if it is set `$scope.multiSelect`as a variable

what I have so far is not much at all...

```
        if ($scope.digitalSelect === Array) {
        console.log('array');
    } else {
        console.log('not array');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to detect if an object is an array you need to use:

```
if(Array.isArray($scope.digitalSelect)){
   console.log('array');
}
else {
    console.log('not array');
}
```

To see if $scope.multiSelect is in the array... you would have to loop through the items in the array and see if array[index]===$scope.multiSelect.   This will only work however if $scope.multiSelect is of type Object.   JavaScript copies objects by reference but if its any other datatype then it will copy by value...  which means that the best you can do is see if the Value of $scope.multiSelect is in the array...

Comment: $scope.multiSelect = Array.isArray($scope.digitalSelect)